# How to run a command over SSH automatically on Windows

Tags: windows, ssh, jenkins, cygwin

I have two Windows boxes. One is Jenkins build server. Second one is deployment box.

I have installed SSH and created a user on the deployment Windows box. I can ssh to it from my Ubuntu workstation and run commands I need to run.

But I need to do this automatically from Jenkins. How to do it? Basically I need to make this automatic:

```
ssh richard@myserver
... enter password ...
cd C:/puppet && git pull
"/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Puppet Labs/Puppet/bin/puppet.bat" apply C:/puppet/manifests/site.pp
```

That's it. Is there some way to do this from a batch file and just execute the *.bat file from Jenkins?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [publish over ssh](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin) plugin allows you to run remote commands.

In *Manage Jenkins* > *Configure System* > *Publish over SSH* you need to configure the remote machine you want to deploy to. Click on *Add* and configure the connection to the server.

In the Job itself add a Build Step *Send files or execute commands over SSH*. Select from the drop down the SSH server you want to connect to. In the *Exec command* you can add all commands you want to have executed on the remote machine.

Comment: That's awesome. I was going crazy. I have tried so many things. I was finally going to write a PowerShell script to do this for me but this is easier.